# TAR a folder with exlcusions

Tags: command-line, 16.04, tar

I'm trying to create a compressed TAR file.   I have a disk that I am going to destroy and would like to take one last snapshot of the /users folder but don't want the users .m4v .m4a and .mp3 files as they are too large.

I tried using this command line

`sudo tar acvf- -exclude='*.m4v' -exclude='*.m4a' -exclude='*.mp3' /home/john/Desktop/KS_UserFolders.tar.gz media/john/OS/Users/`

The message that I get back is

```
john@Pepper:~$ sudo tar acvf- -exclude='*.m4v' -exclude='*.m4a' -exclude='*.mp3' /home/john/Desktop/KS_UserFolders.tar.gz media/john/OS/Users/
[sudo] password for john:
tar: -exclude=*.m4a: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: -exclude=*.mp3: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: /home/john/Desktop/KS_UserFolders.tar.gz: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: media/john/OS/Users: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
john@Pepper:~$
```

I'm sure it's just me getting used to the syntax of Linux, but I can't find a good usage example of TAR that matches my situation, and version of TAR

Comment: 1) it should be `--exclude` (with two dashes), not `-exclude`. 2) You may need to use tar's `--wildcards` option, which I found by looking at the man page (`man tar`): "`--wildcards :  use wildcards with --exclude`"

Comment: I was on that Man page like a fat kid on a piece of cake.  The entry for Wildcards say their enabled by default for exclusions :/

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sudo tar acvf /home/john/Desktop/KS_UserFolders.tar.gz \
  --exclude='*.m4v' \
  --exclude='*.m4a' \
  --exclude='*.mp3' media/john/OS/Users/
```

Note that the archive file name must come right after the `f` option (without a `-`), and the `--exclude` options need two dashes.

If you want it all on one line, it would be

```
sudo tar acvf /home/john/Desktop/KS_UserFolders.tar.gz --exclude='*.m4v' --exclude='*.m4a' --exclude='*.mp3' media/john/OS/Users/
```

Comment: Now it's reporting that there is no such file or directory as

--exclude='*.m4v'
--exclude='*.m4a'

I noticed the syntax of your response includes CR, I assume that the this was just the board munging your post.

Comment: @dotdawtdaught :  Did you include the asterisks in steeldriver 's answer? (And the carriage returns are just for readability)

Comment: I did include the asterisks.

Comment: OK, my apologies -- that was just AskUbuntu's software interpreting your asterisks as italics markers

Comment: No worries, this is a strange issue.  I can't find a syntax reference that elaborates on how to use the -X or -exclude switches for multiple exclusions.